# Grails URL replaces project name

Tags: grails

I converted my app from Grails 1.3.9 to 2.2.0 and now whenever I run the application instead of the URL including the project name, it replaces it with [:].

e.g. `http://localhost:8080/[:]/{controller}/{action}`. The controller and action remain correct it is just occurring with the project name.

Comment: What is in your `Config.groovy` defined in `grails.app.context`?

Comment: I do not see a grails.app.context within Config.groovy

Comment: can you try to define it and set a proper value?

Comment: @innov83r, were you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ran into a similar issue during migration and it was because of the serverUrl config.

I am assuming that the variable to access application name being used in your config, which was valid in previous versions might have been renamed now.

The redirect() method now uses the grails.serverURL config setting to generate the redirect URL. You may need to remove the setting, particularly from the development and test environments. Documented [here.](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html)